# Django REST framework JSON array GET

Tags: python, json, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am running a Django 2.0 and DRF (Django REST Framework) 3.8.0.

I want to be able to GET JSON in a specific format as seen in GOAL NESTED JSON ARRAY.

Right now, I am able to retrieve an JSON Array as shown in MY CURRENT JSON ARRAY. I have checked this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866396/django-rest-framework-json-array-post) and it seems like we have the goal but i was unable to be successful.

I have my model, view and serializer below.
This is achieved by using this:

> GET /studentlectures/1/get_studlect/      ***where 1 is {pk}***

**CURRENT JSON ARRAY:**

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "lecture": 1,
    "student": 1
},
{
    "id": 19,
    "lecture": 4,
    "student": 1
}
]
```

**GOAL NESTED JSON ARRAY**

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "student_code": "60637-009",
        "first_name": "Zoltan",
        "last_name": "Drogo",
        "lectures": [
            {
                "lecture_id": 1,
                "subject_name": "English",
                "teacher_id": 1,
                "teacher_name": "Cirillo Kierans",
                "room": "Room A",
                "schedule": "08:00 AM - 10:00 AM"
            },
            {
                "lecture_id": 2,
                "subject_name": "Math",
                "teacher_id": 3,
                "teacher_name": "Johanna Probate",
                "room": "Room C",
                "schedule": "08:00 AM - 10:00 AM"
            },
            . . . . . . 
}
```

MODEL:

```
class Studentlecture(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, default='')
    lecture = models.ForeignKey(Lecture, default='')
    studentlecture_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='ComputerScience Lectures')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.studentlecture_name}'
```

VIEW:

```
class StudentlectureViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    serializer_class = StudentlectureSerializer
    queryset = Studentlecture.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    #/studentlectures/{pk}/get_studlect/ gives the lectures of student pk
    @action(detail=True)
    def get_studlect(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        student_lectures = Studentlecture.objects.all().filter(student_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        serializer = self.get_serializer(student_lectures, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    #/studentlectures/{pk}/get_lectstud/ gives the students of lecture pk
    @action(detail=True)
    def get_lectstud(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        lecture_students = Studentlecture.objects.all().filter(lecture_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        serializer = self.get_serializer(lecture_students, many=True)
        print(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

SERIALIZER:

```
class StudentlectureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Studentlecture
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'lecture', 'student')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't been able to check back right away, but this what I have done:

```
#/studentlectures/{pk}/get_studlect/ gives the lectures of student pk
@action(detail=True)
def get_studlect(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    student_lectures = Studentlecture.objects.all().filter(student_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    serializer = self.get_serializer(student_lectures, many=True)

    student = Student.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    lecture_nest = serializer.data        

    data = {
      "id": student.values()[0]['id'],
      "student_code": student.values()[0]['student_code'],
      "first_name": student.values()[0]['first_name'],
      "last_name": student.values()[0]['last_name'],
      "lectures": lecture_nest
    }

    return Response(data)
```

I adapted Madi7's answer a bit and I know it looks really dirty but I am changing projects now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RelatedField` for that:

> Serializer

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, IntegerField

from lectures.fields import LectureRelatedField

class StudentLectureSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
    lecture = LectureRelatedField(
        queryset=Lecture.objects.all(), required=True
    )
    ...
```

> lectures.fields

```
from rest_framework.serializers import RelatedField

class LectureRelatedField(RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        data = {
            'lecture_id': obj.lecture_id,
            'subject_name': obj.subject_name,
            'teacher_id': obj.teacher_id,
            'teacher_name': obj.teacher_name,
            'room': obj.room,
            'schedule': obj.schedule
        }
        return data

    def to_internal_value(self, pk):
        return Lecture.objects.get(id=pk)
```

As a result you will get a `json` like this while making requests:

```
"lectures": [
    {
        "lecture_id": 1,
        "subject_name": "English",
        "teacher_id": 1,
        "teacher_name": "Cirillo Kierans",
        "room": "Room A",
        "schedule": "08:00 AM - 10:00 AM"
    },
```